# Interior of $B = \{x \times y \mid x>0 \ \text{and}\ y \neq 0\}$

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

I want to find the interior of $$B = \{x \times y \mid x>0 \ \text{and}\ y  \neq 0\}$$

My attempt:

We will show $B$ is open. Let $x \times y \in B$ and $r: = \text{min}\ \{x, |y|\}$. Then $r>0$. We claim that $B_d (x \times y, r) \subset B$. To prove the inclusion let $x^\prime \times  y^\prime \in B_d(x\times y, r)$, which implies that $d(x^\prime \times y^\prime, x \times y) <x, y$. If $x^\prime \leq 0$ then $x -x^\prime \geq x$, and therefore we have $$d(x^\prime \times y^\prime, x \times y) = \sqrt{(x-x^\prime)^2 + (y-y^\prime)^2} \geq x$$ which is a contradiction. Hence $x >0$.

Now if $y^\prime = 0$, it follows that $$d(x^\prime \times y^\prime, x \times y) = \sqrt{(x-x^\prime)^2 + y^2}>y$$ which is also a contradiction. Hence $y^\prime \neq 0$. Thus, $B$ is open, it follows that $\text{Int } B = B$.

Please check my solution. Is it correct?

Comment: First why this much calculation? Can't this be done...Given $x>0 $ and $y \neq 0$. So either $y>0$ or $y<0$ . If $y>0$ then $x \times y >0$ i.e., $x \times y \in (0, \infty)$ and if $y<0$ then $x \times y \in (-\infty, 0)$ so
$B= (-\infty, 0) \cup (0, \infty)$ which is an open set. Secondly your set is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ so why you take $d_2$ metric?

Answer (score 1):

B is the union of two components, {(x,y)|x> 0, y> 0} and {(x, y)|x> 0, y< 0}.  Each of those is an open set.  Therefore B is open.

Comment: Is because of the first component equals to $(0, +\infty) \times (0, \infty)$ and the second component $(0, +\infty) \times (-\infty, 0)$?

Comment: No!  First, I don't know what you mean by "$\infty$" as opposed to "$+\infty$". More importantly, x is always greater than 0 not equal to it.

Comment: Correction, yes, that is correct.  I don't know why comments can only be edited for five minutes.  It takes me longer than that to type!